# JustGage refresh with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using jquery to refresh my JustGage gauges. I get my data back from the controller and everything works just fine until eventually the pc runs out of memory and it freezes. I have 9 gauges and 2 pie charts that need refreshing. The setInterval call is the problem, as it fires every second instead of waiting 120000 ms. Am I doing something wrong with setInterval?

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
     var g9 = new JustGage({
        id: "gage9",
        value: '@ViewBag.TotalNeuro',
        min: 0,
        max: 150,
        counter: true,
        label: "Total Neuro",
        labelMinFontSize: 11,
        formatNumber: true,
        customSectors: {
            //percents: true,
            ranges: [
                { lo: 0, hi: 33, color: '#f0f016' }, // lo and hi values are in %
                { lo: 34, hi: 67, color: '#f59a1b' },
                { lo: 68, hi: 100, color: '#e0121c' }
            ]
        },
        levelColorsGradient: false,
        gaugeWidthScale: 0.9,
        startAnimationTime: 2700,
        startAnimationType: "bounce",

    });
    setInterval(function () {

    var TotalNeuroUrl = '@Url.Action("TotalNeuro")';
    $.getJSON(TotalNeuroUrl, {}, function (dataNeuro) {
    g9.refresh(dataNeuro);
        }, 120000);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use `setInterval` incorrectly, refer to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Try to modify it to:

```
setInterval(function () {

    var TotalNeuroUrl = '@Url.Action("TotalNeuro")';

    $.getJSON(
        TotalNeuroUrl,
        {},
        function (dataNeuro) {
          g9.refresh(dataNeuro);
        }
    );
},120000);
```